# displaying information in a different HTML page from js

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-graph-api

We are working with the facebook api and have stored the data retrieved in a JSON format into an array. We would like to display this information in a different HTML page but are unable to do so, please help regarding this?

```
<p id="demo"></p>
 <script> var str=""; var names1 = new Array(); //creating names1 array
            getFriendsList = function() { //calling from another function
              FB.api('me/taggable_friends', function(response) { 
                   for (var i = 0; i <= response.data.length; i++) {
                  names1.push(response.data[i].name); str=str+"<br>"+"<br>"+names1[i]; //appending thenames to str 
                  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;//displaying the element in the html page.
                  }
             });
          } </script>
```

Comment: You're going to need to format your question in a way that people can understand. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Uh how is the code related to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I am still a little confused by your question, but I am assuming that you want to know how to display the elements from an array onto your `HTML` page.

If this isn't what you are asking, then just expand on your question and I will see how I can help.

**Explanation for code below**

- You are accessing your `JavaScript` file in your `HTML` by adding the `<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>` reference.
- The `JavaScript` is creating a simple array called `myArray`. We then loop through our array and display content using the `document.write(...);` line.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3];

// for each loop
for (var i in myArray) {
  document.write(myArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: hey thanks for your response. I got it using session storage. :)